# Amazon Sales Channel Unexpected network error, please try again later

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6, amazon

I see other questions and posts on this, but no solutions... so I'm asking again.

When setting up Amazon Sales Channel, The first step is to install API keys that point back to Magento's AWS S3 servers. Those are authenticated as soon as they are saved, and pass. Saving the API keys also checks the Adobe Magento S3 servers for apps and data storage associated with the API keys. If they don't exist, you can create them. The response from that populates fields in Magento with those ARNs. All of that works just fine.

The second step is to go back to the Amazon Sales Channel, and if the API keys are installed, it shows a checklist of things and a button to add (connect) an amazon store. As soon as this page loads, I get the error shown on Screenshot 1. If I click on the button that says "Add Amazon Store", I get the popup shown in Screenshot 2 This makes no sense to me, because at this point, I haven't even told Magento what my Amazon Seller Central account is, so i can't be getting blocked because of my account. There is obviously some kind of API call that happens when the page loads, or maybe there's a javascript file that needs to load that doesn't, or something along those lines, that is not happening. I have nothing in my logs showing any errors.

Screenshot 1
[image: Text]

Screenshot 2
[image: Text]

Any ideas on how to trouble-shoot this?

Answer (score 0):

ok - so in my case, I opened the "inspect" box and clicked on the "console" tab and when the Amazon menu page loaded, an error was thrown due to a product attribute from a module that had been uninstalled a long time ago. The error had to do with GraphQl, but with that error thrown, no other javascript would execute. Removing those attributes from the `eav_attribute` table and clearing the cache solved my problem.